# Saving objects into core data

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data

There is something confuses me a lot... I'm following a tutorial but he didn't cover how most of the code is Done.

The tutorial using `NSManagedObject` Subclasses, the first time he checks for the sample data if it were in the `Core Data` we skip using `return` if the user launches the app for the first time the sample data goes into the Core Data. 
let's take a look.

```
 func inserSampleData()
  {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Bowtie")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "searchKey != nil")

    let count = managedContext.countForFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil)

    if count > 0 { return } //break if we have the sample data already in the core data

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("SampleData", ofType: "plist")

    let dataArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path!)

    for dict in dataArray!
    { //1
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Bowtie", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedContext)
        let bowtie = Bowtie(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.managedContext)
        let btDict = dict as! NSDictionary

       //// SOME CODE

        var error: NSError?

        if !managedContext.save(&error)
        {
            println("Some error \(error?.userInfo)")
        }

    }
  }
```

As in comment 1, he uses `NSEntityDescription` to get an an object of an entity, 
i believe we do so, to save our sample data into Core data, which can't be Done unless we call `NSEntityDescription`...

let's take a look at the 2nd `func wear()`

```
  func wear() {
    //currentBowtie is an instance of the NSManagedObject Subclass
    let times = currentBowtie.timesWorn.integerValue
    currentBowtie.timesWorn = NSNumber(integer: times + 1)
    currentBowtie.lastWorn = NSDate()

    var error: NSError?

    if managedContext.save(&error)
    {
        println("unable to save \(error) \(error?.userInfo)")
    }

  }
```

According the 2nd function he saved Directly to the disk, without specifying an Entity, also he didn't call `NSEntityDescription.entityForName...`

So how the application knew in which entity to save ?

Why he called `NSEntityDescription` in `Func insertSampleData()`, & he didn't use it in `func wear()` ?

Answer (score 1):

While the creation of a new Bowtie in Core Data, you need an entity description.

`currentBowtie` has already been created, so playing around with it further, and saving it doesn't require an entity description.